# Flutter build apk Release failed ImagePickerPlugin

Tags: flutter, dart

After updating flutter to null safety. I updated my library but when I create the release build and install it on the mobile it gives me this error

```
    java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Interface androidx.lifecycle.c implemented by class io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin$LifeCycleObserver is inaccessible (declaration of 'io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin$LifeCycleObserver' appears in /data/app/~~8gseV7LnSGpcr_IhhJAk_Q==pakage name--UH6bVsi-ND4jit95tOoJQ==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
```

Comment: Are you using a package called image picker? And if so, are you using the latest version of the package?

Comment: not using the latest version of it. Because the latest version is image_picker: ^0.7.2 which have null safty.

Comment: @Apealed and if I update image picker then it give me this error                    
   Because image_picker >=0.7.0 depends on image_picker_platform_interface ^2.0.0 which depends on http ^0.13.0, image_picker >=0.7.0 requires http ^0.13.0.
So, because vahak depends on both http ^0.12.2 and image_picker ^0.7.2, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because vahak depends on both http ^0.12.2 and image_picker ^0.7.2, version solving failed.)

Answer (score 1):

delete widget_test.dart file in test folder below lib folder of the project and rebuild the project it will help u .

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer just go and delete the image plugin from GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java class. It is working for me. Like need to replace it with register